# how does a do while loop used provide user prompt?

Tags: c

I made a simple program to make a half- triangle representing with # everything works fine only thing is that my do while loop in not working not able to prompt the user quick help?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    do { 
        printf("enter a non negitive number less than equal to 23");
        scanf("%d\n",&n);

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {  
            for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++)
            {  
                if(j <= n-(i+2) )
                    printf(" ");
                else
                    printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }  
    }     
    while(n < 23);

    printf("thanks for using my program");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Not working" how?  What happens, and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Are you checking the return value from `scanf`?

Comment: @cdhowie when i input n > 23 it still prints the triangle which i don't want

Comment: @user3315556 Because the condition is evaluated at the end of each iteration of the loop, not at the beginning.  Which loop mechanism might you use if you want to check the condition at the beginning?

Comment: @cdhowie i can use a if else for that matter....but i want ask the user for the input again and again until he enters a correct value how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your problem is that it prints output even when you enter a number over 23.  (I am repeating this because this information is not present in the question itself.)

This is because the condition is evaluated at the *end* of a `do ... while` loop.  You need to test the condition immediately after reading the input if you want to exit immediately after the number is read.

Try encapsulating the print-and-read logic in a function; this will make it easier to use as the condition in a `while` loop.

```
int prompt_and_read(int * output) {
    printf("enter a non negitive number less than equal to 23: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    return scanf("%d\n", output);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
while (prompt_and_read(&n) && n < 23) {
    ....
}
```

This is an improvement in multiple ways:

- It flushes the output in order to make sure that the prompt gets displayed.  `printf()` may not flush the output until a newline is written.
- The loop will terminate immediately if it reads a number 23 or larger.
- Because you were not checking the return value of `scanf()`, if the input ended before a number 23 or larger was read, the loop would continue infinitely.  Testing the result of `scanf()` fixes this by terminating the loop if no input could be read.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking...

Standard output is *line-buffered*, meaning output won't appear on the console until the buffer is full *or* you send a newline *or* you manually flush with `fflush()`.

Try the following:

```
printf("enter a non negitive number less than equal to 23: ");
fflush( stdout );
scanf("%d",&n);
```

The call to `fflush` will force the output to appear on your console.

Comment: Doesn't a call to `scanf` flush `stdout`?

Comment: @RSahu: No. Why would you expect it to?

Comment: I seem to be mistaken. I thought it did. But apparently it doesn't have to.